# Two digits after dot in toString

Tags: java, decimal, digits

I managed to make these two classess, but "score" has to have 7 digits after the dot. I cannot modify Main class. I think I should use String.format("%.7f", ...) but I don't know where. Please help.

**MAIN:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc c = new Calc();
        String score = c.doCalc(args[0]);
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

**CALC:**

```
public class Calc {
    public String doCalc(String cmd) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        try {
            return engine.eval(cmd).toString();
        }
        catch (ScriptException e) {
            return "Invalid command to calc";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `system.out.println`, you should use `system.out.format` or `system.out.printf`. See a short tutorial from Oracle on using it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). Why exactly can't you modify the main class? That seems to be where your score is being printed..

Comment: I know I should edit Main, but I can't because it's my studies task. I can only modify Calc :/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string result back to `Double` and feed it to `String.format`:

```
try {
    return String.format("%.7f", Double.valueOf(engine.eval(cmd).toString()));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    return "Invalid command to calc";
}
```

You could of course feed the result directly to `String.format` without the `toString` and `valueOf` round trip, like so:

```
return String.format("%.7f", engine.eval(cmd));
```

But that only works when the eval result is a valid floating point number. To deal with other cases like integers or non-numbers, you'd have to put in a few type checks and make the code look more cluttered.